# is it possible to capture the BottomNavigationBarItem double click event in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am capture the double click in flutter navigate button using `GestureDetector` like this way:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: viewService.buildComponent("homelist"),
      bottomNavigationBar: GestureDetector(
        onDoubleTap: () {
          _onItemDoubleTapped();
        },
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.cruiseNavigatorHome),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.subscriptions), label: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.cruiseNavigatorSubscribe),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.rss_feed), label: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.cruiseNavigatorChannel),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.school), label: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.cruiseNavigatorMine),
            ],
            currentIndex: state.selectIndex,
            fixedColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            onTap: _onItemTapped,
            unselectedItemColor: Color(0xff666666),
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed),
      ));
```

double click item trigger `_onItemDoubleTapped` event works fine, but now I want to capture the double click of each navigator item. Is it possible to capture the double click event in flutter? I have also tried like this way:

```
return Scaffold(
    body: viewService.buildComponent("homelist"),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: InkWell(
                  onDoubleTap: () {
                    _onItemDoubleTapped();
                  },
                  child: Icon(Icons.home)),
              label: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.cruiseNavigatorHome),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: InkWell(
                  onDoubleTap: () {
                    final SubListDefaultController subListDefaultController = Get.put(SubListDefaultController());
                    subListDefaultController.isScrollTop = true;
                  },
                  child: Icon(Icons.subscriptions)),
              label: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.cruiseNavigatorSubscribe),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.rss_feed), label: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.cruiseNavigatorChannel),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.school), label: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.cruiseNavigatorMine),
        ],
        currentIndex: state.selectIndex,
        fixedColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        unselectedItemColor: Color(0xff666666),
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed),
  );
```

the `InkWell` works with double tap but did not trigger the single tap event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parent GestureDetector of your BottomNavigationBar and replace inkwell with GestureDetector and then set the **behavior** of your GestureDetector to **HitTestBehavior.translucent**.

Comment: how to know which item was double tapped? @Santo Shakil

Comment: Updated the answer. Check please.

Comment: It works. Seems unnesassary to set the HitTestBehavior.translucent. @Santo Shakil